# Mobile Development - Embed HTML/CSS within Webview connected to a server

Tags: android, html, css, webview

Since few time I'm interested to learn about mobile development (Android) and I've learnt that it exists some ways to develop cross-platform applications by using HTML/CSS/JS pages embed as ressources and displayed in a webview.

My question is : Is it possible to send POST and GET requests from the embed website, in order to exchange datas with a server ?

Comment: Hi , Read this page 'http://codecondo.com/7-best-html5-based-frameworks-for-developing-cross-platform-apps/'